# Managing projects with cousin: How Projectlocker.com can help?

Tags: project-management, blogs, wiki

I'm about to go through a new experience with my cousin who is also a software engineer. We have few ideas that we like to turn into software applications.

We are currently collaborating via email to record our ideas and thoughts. But to manage our little project and control source code and track our issues.

Now my question is: How can I make use of the wiki and blog feature so that we don't have to write emails? It is nice to be able to document our work in a formating friendly environment.

Answer (score 2):

I work for ProjectLocker and might be able to help.

[ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com) hosts [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org), which can be useful for managing your ideas and turning them into applications.  A wiki in general is designed to allow users to rapidly share information, so you can use the wiki as a virtual whiteboard, jotting down and editing ideas and refining them.  The ability to add multiple pages is as simple as using a CamelCase name; you can add links for additional pages and information at will.  You make an agreement with your design partners to share relevant information in the Wiki, and then you can stop writing e-maiils; it's all captured there.

Once you start getting down to the details of development, Trac's ticketing system can be useful.  You manage issues, prioritize them, and then when you check in fixes, you can add tags to your commit to indicate that the tickets should be automatically closed by ProjectLocker.

If you have more specific questions, you can open a ticket in the ProjectLocker Portal, which you can log into using your ProjectLocker e-mail and password, and someone can assist.